# Last 4 digits are getting converted to 0 while writing to excel using Panda and ExcelWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter with Panda to write an excel. Doing so 19-character long value is getting changed from **9223781998151429879** to **9223781998151420000**. Excel [handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/long-numbers-incorrectly-in-excel) of long numbers might be the reason.

I tried to remove the formatting using the below code. I tried various combinations of formats. But nothing worked.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Result 1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Result 1']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
worksheet.set_column('M:M', 20, format1)
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason can be that [Excel supports long numbers up to 15 digits precision](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

[image]

A work around is to write numbers as text to excel:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[9223781998151429879]], columns=['num'])

with pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_column_formats.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df['num'] = df['num'].apply(str)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Result 1')
```

This data format works as a number with numeric calculations:

[image]

**Update:**

Also refer [answers on this post](https://superuser.com/questions/373997/adding-more-than-15-digits-in-excel)